# cv2.VideoCapture doesn't work within docker container

Tags: python, opencv, docker, video-capture

I am trying to use cv2.VideoCapture to capture image from a docker container.

`import cv2
vid = cv2.VideoCapture('path\to\video')
ret, frame = vid.read()`

In terms of the video file,
I have tried 
either mount the file with `docker -v`
or `docker cp` to copy the video file into container,
but both with no luck (ret returns False).

Should I add any command when launching the container?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about docker run --net="host" ? Does that fixes it?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution? I tried @WurmD approach with ```docker run --net="host"```, but then I got a docker error; ```docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "--net=host": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled 
```

Answer (score -1):

There might be 2 problems:

1) In your container opencv is not installed properly. To check that do print(ret, frame). If they come (false, None). Then opencv has not installed properly.

2) The file you are using is corrupted. To check that try to copy any image file (jpg) into the container and use cv2.imread to read the image and then print it. If numpy array comes then while copying your file is not getting corrupted.

The best option is pull any opencv + python image and then create a container with it. The better option is use dockerfiles of these images to create the container.

Comment: I have opencv correctly installed (it's a one-line pip3 command), and the files are not corrupted. When running the code via the container entrypoint, it doesn't work, returns FPS 0.0 for videos, etc. When I run the exact same python code while logged into the container, it works fine.